# Is there an open source slideshow to video converter?

Tags: open-source, video, file-converter, slideshow, libreoffice

Being a Libre Office user, I am having trouble finding a solution to convert my slides to video. I tried [Xilisoft](http://www.xilisoft.com/powerpoint-to-video-converter-free.html), however there were some troubles like the same software was unable to read my Libre Office Slide, which I saved as pptx format.

The other detail which I would like to mention here is that I record audio and often embed these audios in my slides.

So my question, is there a software (preferably free and open source <sup>**#**</sup> ) which can convert my Libre Office Impress slides to video *directly* <sup>**##**</sup> ?

---

***#** : Preferably without watermarks* 
***##** : No screen recorders please*

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, @SeverusSnape?

Comment: @ool No. Not yet.